# How does minimax and/or alpha-beta search help play games?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I understand how minimax and alpha-beta algorithms work. But I can't understand how they are able to find a good solution. How can alternatively selecting the minimum and maximum values in consecutive levels of a game tree provide a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Typically these tree searches are applied in situations where the AI is playing against another opponent. In other words, two players take turns: the AI which is trying to win, and the opponent which is trying to prevent the AI from winning. The AI can't just maximize an objective function, it must search for the move which doesn't have a good way for its opponent to counter (minimize the objective function). Thus, it tries to find a path through a min-max tree with the highest end value, where it alternates AI maximizes, opponent minimizes, AI maximizes...